# Export excel as write protected or readOnly using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery plugin to export excel and its working file. 
But i want to export excel which is write protected.

```
$("#resultsTable").table2excel({
      exclude: ".noExl",
      name: "Results"
  });
```

Is there any another way to export excel which is write protected so that after export its can't be edited.

Comment: That sounds like something to ask the vendor of that plugin.  Does the plugin claim to support such a feature?  Are its options and usage documented somewhere?

Comment: Is there any another way of doing this as well.

Comment: Well, you could fork the source code for that project and add that feature.  Or find other plugins which may support that feature.  But if you're asking for this community to recommend a plugin for you, that's off-topic here.